# To what platforms can the blender game engine build to?

Tags: blender, blender-game-engine

I used to use the BGE until I found that unity can build to lots of different platforms. What platforms does the BGE support?

Comment: -1 That's more a google search!

Comment: Honestly, looking for blender documentation can sometimes be a minefield. With http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=what+platform+does+the+blender+game+engine+support%3F
we get some results, but wikipedia shows the previous version 2.49 and the forum entries are mostly random. The first result might give something if you wade through the official site although I often find the official documentation hazy. Asking here or on the forums is often easier and lot faster than googling. Thats not to say that the right query will find the answer though

Comment: I feel the need to mention my [3D Graphics &Modeling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications?referrer=xAhz58gd3XAN5QfMOt5KEg2) proposal, which includes Blender. It's still in commitment phase, feel free to help move it to Beta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows, linux and mac. Although google may have helped a little, I think you might find more answers here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?34-Game-Engine

I think it is better to use Blender to make the assets and Unity as a game engine. I only use Blender as a hobby for modelling and scripting but I think Unity will provide a better base for game development. It helps that there is a free indie version and this year they created a steam like store where you could sell a game making distribution that much easier. Sometimes the blender game engine does not play so nicely with some graphics cards, you might find evidence of this frustration in the forums.

Comment: Yes; I've used both, and BGE is good for demos and little more. Honestly it is hard to create a salesworthy game with that, and the poorly-organised nature of the Blender documentation does not help, particularly when compared with Unity which is brilliant for docs.